# Read Java variable value in bash

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have a Java class called `InputTxt` and it has an int attribute `id`. I want to write a shell script that creates a file with `id` as the file name.

**NOTE:** The java function that calls this script returns something other than the `id`.

Comment: So what is stopping you from writing the shell script?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you actually want to do here. Different instances of a class could have different values in that field. Which one would you like to use? Also why are you even trying to do this. It seems like a unnecessarily complicated way to do this... It would be much easier to do this from a java program. Is there anything preventing you to do this using a java program?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `id` as a parameter to the script:

```
import java.io.*;

class InputTxt {

    static int id;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        id = args.length;
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                        new String[]{"touch", Integer.toString(id)});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

Sample run:

```
$ javac InputTxt.java
$ java InputTxt 4 5 6
$ ls
3  InputTxt.class  InputTxt.java
```